# Why does List.scan append a value to the head of a list?

Tags: f#

I'm sure this problem is trivial, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Suppose I have a list and I want to get the cumulative product of the list:

```
> let li = [1; 2; 3; 4;];;
  val li : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

I can do this with `List.scan`:

```
> li |> List.scan (fun acc value -> acc * value) 1;;
  val it : int list = [1; 1; 2; 6; 24]
```

Notice the result is exactly 1 `int` longer. That `int` is the `1` in the front. Now, when you go to the microsoft webpage on [List.scan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.scan['t,'state]-function-[fsharp]), their example seems to return the exact same amount of elements. I don't see any place where they chop the extra element off.

Now, I can simply chop the leading element off:

```
> li |> List.scan (fun acc value -> acc * value) 1 |> List.tail;;
  val it : int list = [1; 2; 6; 24]
```

and I get my result list. However, I am confused. The function is described as

> This function takes the second argument, and applies the function to it and the first element of the list. Then, it passes this result into the function along with the second element, and so on.

To me, this would leave me with a list of the same size as the original, right? How are we getting an extra element?

Comment: You left out an important part of the documentation: "Finally, it returns the list of intermediate results _and_ the final result.".
Also, `[] |> List.scan f n` = n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description finishes like this:

> Finally, it returns the list of intermediate results **and** the final result.

The "and" suggests that it returns one extra element. Maybe it would be clearer if it mentioned that returns the initial state **and** the list of results.

Either way it seems to be a feature of the function. If the extra value is not required then`List.tail` chops it off.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage on List.scan gives an example where `transactions` has 6 elements, and `balances = [1122.73 ... 1257.31]` has 7 elements. (For correct accounting the code should be `printfn "$%10.2f $%10.2f" transactions.[i] balances.[i]`).

The output of `List.scan f s l` satisfies:

```
o.[0] = s
o.[i] = f(o.[i-1],l.[i-1])
```

This defines `o[i]` for `i in 0 .. l.Length`. So `o.Length` is naturally `l.Length+1`.